# How to make react app listen to redux store conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a React app for University Management.

Below is my router:

```
<Route path="selecting/" component={SelectUniversity}>
    <Route path="myUniversity" component={MyUniversity} />
    <Route path="studentdetails" component={AddStudentDetails} />
    <Route path="payment" component={Payment} />
</Route>
```

the flow is==>MyUniversity==>AddStudentDetails==>Payment
As per this, everything is working as expected 
All the three components **MyUniversity, AddStudentDetails, Payment** are extensivly using **redux store**

MyUniversity's **mapStateToProps** is as follows

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { results } = state.results

  const studentData = state.results.studentData
  return {
    results,
    studentData,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ ...Actions, ...studentActions }, dispatch)
}
```

there are many store variables involved, this is for sample purpose
Similarly, separate mapstaetoprops and mapdispatchtoprops for other two component.

Now the requirement is (for some unavoidable reasons):-

if a user directly lands on myuniversity page with a id like this below:-
http://mywebsite.com/myuniversity/9999,
I need to get the data associated with 9999 (which am already getting) and execute the same flow.

my updated router

```
<Route path="selecting/" component={SelectUniversity}>
    <Route path="myUniversity" component={MyUniversity} />
    <Route path="myUniversity/:unidetails" component={MyUniversity} />
    <Route path="studentdetails" component={AddStudentDetails} />
    <Route path="payment" component={Payment} />
</Route>
```

Once I get the data how can I update the redux store so that the existing flow will work as expected.

I know I can dispatch as many actions as i want once we get the data from ajax call but like I said there are 15-20 different state variables are involved for each of the three component. So, it does not seem like a scalable approach to fire so many dispatchers on each component load.

**Approach 2**
So I came up with another approach:-
1. Define a new reducer.
2. Upon getting data store the entire ajax result in your desired format in the state.
3. Now go to the mapstatetoprops of each of the three components and add conditions on every every prop level whether get data from pevious reducer or current reducer.

for example:-
lets say i have added another reducer called **universitydetails**
then my mapstatetoprops will look something like this

```
const { results } = state.results || state.universitydetails

const studentData = state.results.studentData || state.universitydetails.studentData

return {
        results,
        studentData,
      }
```

then again, adding condition at each prop level (given that i am using 15-20 different state variables in each of the three components)

**Approach 3**:-
add redux-saga and dispatch action on myuniversity load and yield other actions based on it
But this wont be generic. Incase, I want to add simliar feature for other things such as **hostel** then again i need to add sagas for this hostlels and need to dispatch action on initial load.

What I think will be best approach (correct me if am wrong) :-
Define a new reducer and **somehow** make my component listens to this reducer(like approach 2 but without uglifying the code) so that in case i want to add another feature like hostelselector, i just need to update my new reducer structure and make my component listen to this new reducer

I am stuck at **somehow**
Any suggestion how to go about this?

Comment: So basically you have a page (AddStudentDetails) that will get data from different sources based on a condition? So you might have n-pages that will flow to the same one (AddStudentDetails) and this page will have to be able to read these data regardless?

Comment: @Ematipico We have n sources which will land on myuniversity component
from there i need to maintain the flow like addsudentdetails then payment.
Let me know if you still have any questions

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I understood how's the flow of your application and that's my idea.

You can create one reducer that will respond to just one action called 'SET_SOURCE'. There it will put the name of the current source where you should extract your data from. Ideally it should be the name of the reducer/object where your data will be hold.

After that you have to create a reducer for each source. Every source will be responsible of itself and they won't interact each other. That means that when your ajax call will be finished and you will have to save your data inside inside the store (aka firing an action), you will fire the action to trigger the reducer that you want.

The structure of your reducers could be like this:

```
=> myUniversity
      => currentSource
      => sources
            => uniDetails
            => hostel etc.
```

You can achieve this kind of structure using `combineReducers` function

```
// myUniversityReducer.js
import uniDetails from 'uniDetailsReducer'
import hostel from 'hostelReducer'
import currentSource from 'currentSourceReducer'

const sources = combineReducers({hostel, uniDetails})
const myUniversity = combineReducers({currentSource, sources})

export myUniversity
```

Inside your `mapStateToProps` you could something like to select the current source:

```
function mapDispatchToProps = (state) => {
  const currentSource = selectCurrentSource(state) // currentSource = 'uniDetails' => name of the reducer
  const dataFromSource = selectDataFromSources(state, currentSource) // dataFromSource = state[currentSource] => object inside uniDetails

  // ... if here you need to manipulate data because the structure of every
  // source is different, you can have your function that will do that based on the source name

  return { ...dataFromSource }
}
```

That's my idea but there might be the chance that I missed something or I misunderstood some of the scenario